# Why was this NAA flag on a "What OS are you using?" 'answer' disputed?

Tags: discussion, comments, disputed-flags

This old answer from 2012 at [sys.stdout not reassigning to sys.__stdout__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719328/sys-stdout-not-reassigning-to-sys-stdout/12719351#12719351) (now deleted, thanks to the meta-effect)

- starts by "It worked for me:"
- in the middle, the exact code OP posted
- ends by "What OS are you using?"

It doesn't answer the question like *never*, has 0 upvotes. So I flagged it as "not an answer" (cleaning old site questions never hurts), and the flag was disputed ([4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16765809) people out of 5 found it OK!)

It should be a comment at best (like, you may have made a typo or typed your code on a ZX81, so it doesn't work for you but without reason), useful in that case.

Is that because answerer has a high rep (now)? Roboviewing at its worst?

Comment: I think it's because the [reviewers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16765809) thought it's a valid answer. If you ignore the fact that its code is identical to OP's code, it may look a valid answer (of questionable quality). Feel free to hit the delete button on that "answer".

Comment: @Floern already did (and someone else did too, meta effect). Well, bye bye now... I may delete the question since there's no problem anymore. But still: 4 people out of 5 found that OK what the hell!!

Comment: I can always count on vaultah to flag as duplicate & take out the trash. Guess where my vote will go :)

Comment: "Not an answer" flags are for *obvious* non-answers.

Comment: when it starts by "your code works for me", and ends with an asking for clarification, then it should be a comment.

Comment: Not necessarily. It **is** an attempt to answer and that's what matters when naa flags are evaluated.

Comment: @Shadow ok I see your point. A feeble attempt to say the least. Not everyone shares that point of view but I respect that.

Comment: Did it say, "**It** worked for me" or did it say, "**Your code** worked for me"? Because I keep seeing answers that say, "This worked for me" and the code in the answer is new code that (presumably) fixes the problem in the question.

Comment: As far as my eye could see it was the exact OP code. And if it wasnt then some dxplanation of the difference would have been required.

Comment: Quote: *cleaning old site questions never hurts*.  I can't tell if that was a typo, but using NAA on an *answer* will certainly hurt if that was the goal.  Just don't ask others to do what you can do, DV the answer, refresh, click Delete.

Comment: @HansPassant yes, I did that and the meta-effect did the rest. It's not a typo, but an execution in a different console type. Still I fail to see how it's an answer to tell that the OP code works in an answer. But maybe that's a matter of opinion. I'll keep flagging those anyway.